# how can I get rid : TypeError: communityApp.activeTabLayout.pforum is undefined

Tags: backbone.js

**my code of module is.**

spine.module('communityApp', {
    startWithParent: false,
    define: function (communityApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
        console.log("communityApp.js");

```
    // Setup the router for this module
    var Router = Marionette.AppRouter.extend({
        before: function () {
            console.log("communityApp.js: router.before()")
            App.startSubApp("communityApp", {});
        },
        appRoutes: {
            "community": "showCommunityTab",
            "community/pforum": "getPforum",
            "community/questions":"getQuestions",
            "community/events": "getEvents"
        }
    });

    // Startup router
    App.addInitializer(function () {
        console.log("communityApp.js: App.addInitializer()")
        // contains active controller
        communityApp.activeController = new communityApp.Controllers.tabController();
        // initializing route
        communityApp.Router = new Router({
            controller: communityApp.activeController
        });
    });

    // Let app know we started
    communityApp.addInitializer(function () {
        console.log("communityApp.js: DemoApp.addInitializer()");
        App.vent.trigger("app:started", "communityApp");
    });

    // This will run when a sub app (module) starts
    communityApp.on("start", function () {
        console.log("communityApp.js: on 'Start'()");
    });
```

**code of controller is.**

spine.module("communityApp", function (communityApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    "use strict";

```
// initializing controllers and collections for message tabs
communityApp.Controllers = {};
communityApp.Collections = {};

communityApp.Controllers.tabController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    showCommunityTab: function () {
        this.getCommunityTab();
    },
    getCommunityTab: function (data) {
        //var tabLayout = new communityApp.Views.tabLayout();
        //tabLayout.render();
        // creating active layout
        communityApp.activeTabLayout = new communityApp.Views.tabLayout();
        communityApp.activeTabLayout.render();
        // loading community module view
        App.regionMain.show(communityApp.activeTabLayout);
        // load pforum on community module load
        this.getPforum();
    },
    getPforum : function(){
        console.log('Public Forum Tab');
        var pforum = new communityApp.Controllers.pforumController();
        pforum.init();

    },
    getQuestions : function(){
        console.log('Question tab');
        var questions = new communityApp.Controllers.questionsController();
        questions.init();

    },
    getEvents : function(){
        console.log('Events tab');
        var events = new communityApp.Controllers.eventController();
        events.init();

    }
});
```

**Code where error is, Its a tab page.**

spine.module("communityApp", function (communityApp, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _) {
    "use strict";

```
communityApp.Controllers.pforumController = Marionette.Controller.extend({
    init: function(){
        var func = _.bind(this._getPforum, this);
        $.when(App.request('alerts1:entities' , {origin:'pforum'}))
            .then(func)
    },
    _getPforum:function(data){

        // populating the data
        communityApp.activeTabLayout.pforum.show(new communityApp.CollectionViews.pforumCollectionViews({
            collection: data
        }));
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're creating the `activeTabLayout` in `getCommunityTab`, and you're trying to access it after creating the controller in `getPforum`. These are both attached to separate routes. Therefore you're not guarenteed that `communityApp.activeTabLayout` exists inside of your `init` method.

`community/pforum` -> creates your controller, but not your tab layout.

`community` -> creates your tab layout, but not your controller.

You need to make sure `communityApp.activeTabLayout = new communityApp.Views.tabLayout();` runs before `pforum.init();`